# Multiple categories filter

Tags: categories

I have a channel section called Members. I have 2 category groups (categoriesMembres & cantons).

My goal: show entries only related to a specific category in categoriesMembres and loop through the cantons:

Canton1

- entry 1
- entry 2
- etc.

Canton2

- entry 3
- entry 4
- etc.

Right now the code below display it like that:

Canton1

- entry 1
- entry 2
- entry 3
- entry 4

Canton2

- entry 1
- entry 2
- entry 3
- entry 4

The code (I stripped out html for clarity)

```
{% set membersCat = craft.categories.group('categoriesMembres').title('Membre').first() %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('listeMembres').relatedTo(membersCat) %}
{% set cantonsCat = craft.categories.group('cantons').relatedTo(entries) %}

{% for canton in cantonsCat %}
   {{ canton.title }}
   {% for row in entries|batch(3) %}
    {% for entry in row %}
     {{ entry.title }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

What am I overseeing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to filter for entries related to your "Canton" category only within your cantons loop.
Add another ElementCriteriaModel and get entries related to both `membersCat` and `canton`:

```
{% for canton in cantonsCat %}
    {% set entriesInCanton = craft.entries.section('listeMembres').relatedTo('and', membersCat, canton) %}    
    {% for row in entriesInCanton|batch(3) %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Another approach (only works if there's one "Canton" max per entry!) would be to make use of Craft's `group` filter. This is probably the better way to solve your problem, because it doesn't add extra DB queries for each "Canton" iterated over in your loop.

```
{% set membersCat = craft.categories.group('categoriesMembres').title('Membre').first() %}
{% set cantonsCats = craft.categories.group('cantons') %}
{% set cantonsCatsInUse = craft.categories.group('cantons').relatedTo(entries) %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('listeMembres').relatedTo('and', membersCat, cantonsCats) %}
{% set entriesByCanton = entries|group('myCantonCategoryField.first()') %}

{% for canton, entriesInCanton in entriesByCanton %}
    {% for row in entriesInCanton|batch(3) %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This probably won't output the cantons in the sort order you whish, but this fortunatelly can be solved easily.

```
{% set entriesByCanton = entriesByCanton|supersort('ksort') %}
```

Comment: The second approach is best as I have only one canton for each entry and it truly save DB queries. Thanks carlcs!