# Output Matrix in relation to category

Tags: matrix, categories, relations

I'm setting up an FAQ page using a matrix. Each Matrix block contains a question and an answer field. Each Q+A needs to be outputted within a section on the same page such as General, Payments...

I've figured the best way to do this is using categories to assign the Q+As section, limiting each Q+A to one category. I'd then need to output all Q+As for each section with it's category as a header.

Desired Output:

```
<h2>General</h2>

<p>Question field output</p>
<p>Answer field output</p>

<p>Question field output</p>
<p>Answer field output</p>

<h2>Payments</h2>

<p>Question field output</p>
<p>Answer field output</p>

....
```

I'm fairly new to craft so perhaps I'm overcomplicating it by assigning it to a category, it seems like it's the easiest way to add new Q+As and for them to appear within the right section.

How would I go about outputting this? I've set up a Category Group called 'faqCategories'

Here's my matrix setup:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's tempting to use the Matrix block for things that might actually be better as a a channel or a structure.  I thing this might be the case here.

The way you've set it up is fine, relating each FAQ to a category is a good approach.

In any event, the plugin `groupBy` should help you:

https://github.com/timkelty/groupby-craft

Or you can look at this example:

http://craftcookbook.net/recipes/279

Comment: Thanks. After your comment I'm now using a structure instead where each section (General, Payment..)  is now an entry rather than a category, and then I have the matrix inside each entry to add as many Q+A as required.  All gets outputted in my singles FAQ page.

Comment: I just had another look at the `groupBy` plugin, but I can't figure out what it does in addition to Craft's `group` filter. @khalwat

Comment: See examples: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/8665/125, http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/9959/125